# Sharing external HDD from Ubuntu to Windows Vista

Tags: networking, file-sharing, lan, windows-vista

My first question over here. I am struggling with getting a share working properly. Please advise whether the logs and prints are viable and what else you may need.

I have a pretty-much corrupted Vista notebook that is blue-screening on USB plug in/plug out. The notebook is close to end its lifespan so I don't bother fixing it.

I want to plug my HDD to my ubuntu netbook which serves me as a remote storage basically. This way I can skip the awful BSoD on Vista if the HDD gets unplugged by mistake.

My network consists of Thomson modem which receives the Internet signal. It is wired to DIR-600 DLink wireless router to which my devices are connecting.

I have connected USB drive to my Ubuntu netbook, performed shares-admin share with R/W permissions.  And I tried mapping that drive from Windows machine, the fun begins:

```
C:\Windows\system32>ping 192.168.0.12

Pinging **192.168.0.12** with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from **192.168.0.101**: Destination host unreachable.
Reply from 192.168.0.101: Destination host unreachable.
Reply from 192.168.0.101: Destination host unreachable.
Reply from 192.168.0.101: Destination host unreachable.
```

While, 192.168.0.101 is the Vista machine which I am pinging from. I started wondering what happens, the ARP /ICMP issue? Why is my machine even in the list of route?
`IPconfig /all` from my Windows machine:

```
Windows IP Configuration

   The host name. . . . . . . . . . . Gabriela-PC
   Primary DNS Suffix. . :
   Type of the node. . . . . . . . . . . . : Hybrid
   IP Routing Enabled. . . . . . . Do not
   WINS Proxy Enabled. . . . Do not

Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection 2:

   State media. . . . . . . . . . .: Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix:
   Description. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . : Bluetooth Personal Area Network
   Physical address. . . . . . . . . . : 00-03-7A-81-78-C0
   DHCP enabled. . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration enabled. . . . : Yes

Wireless LAN Wireless Network Connection:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix:
   Description. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . Intel (R) PRO / Wireless 3945ABG Network Con
nection
   Physical address. . . . . . . . . . : 00-1F-3C-76-27-55
   DHCP enabled. . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration enabled. . . . : Yes
   Link-local IPv6 Address. : Fe80 :: 1d96: 6b7d: 1760:908 e% 10 (Preferred)

   IPv4 address. . . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.101 (Preferred)
   The subnet mask. . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Lease Obtained. . . . . . . . : February 20, 2013 5:50:33
   The lease expires. . . . . . . . . : February 27, 2013 5:50:36
   Default Gateway. . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.1
   DHCP server. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.1
   DHCPv6 IAID ID. . . . : 251666236
   DHCPv6 Client DUID: 00-01-00-01-10-0A-91-79-00-1E-68-70-8F-10

   DNS servers. . . . . . . . . . . : 62.179.1.63
                                       62.179.1.62
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . : On

Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection:

   State media. . . . . . . . . . .: Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix:
   Description. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . Marvell Yukon PCI-E 88E8040T Fast Ethernet
t Controller
   Physical address. . . . . . . . . . : 00-1E-68-70-8F-10
   DHCP enabled. . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration enabled. . . . : Yes

Tunnel adapter Local Area Connection *:

   State media. . . . . . . . . . .: Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix:
   Description. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . : Isatap. {EAC8232A-2F30-4FB6-8F66-FAA69C4AE
976}
   Physical address. . . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP enabled. . . . . . . . . . Do not
   Autoconfiguration enabled. . . . : Yes

Tunnel adapter Local Area Connection * 3:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix:
   Description. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . : Teredo Tunneling Pseudo-Interface
   Physical address. . . . . . . . . . 02-00-54-55-4E-01
   DHCP enabled. . . . . . . . . . Do not
   Autoconfiguration enabled. . . . : Yes
   IPv6 address. . . . . . . . . . . . : 2001:0:9 d38: 6ab8: 242C: 2f27: 3f57: ff9a (Pref
Erowa)
   Link-local IPv6 Address. : Fe80 :: 242C: 2f27: 3f57: ff9a% 9 (Preferred)

   Default Gateway. . . . . . . . . . :::
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . : Off

Tunnel adapter Local Area Connection * 7:
Tunnel adapter Local Area Connection * 7:

   State media. . . . . . . . . . .: Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix:
   Description. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . : Isatap. {274797EC-4B95-E7AC-947F-FCA2DE2D2
B07}
   Physical address. . . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP enabled. . . . . . . . . . Do not
   Autoconfiguration enabled. . . . : Yes

Tunnel adapter Local Area Connection * 9:

   State media. . . . . . . . . . .: Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix:
   Description. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . : Isatap. {24D921F5-CC7F-4123-8C91-9900221A7
3E1}
   Physical address. . . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP enabled. . . . . . . . . . Do not
   Autoconfiguration enabled. . . . : Yes
```

`Route print` from my Windows machine:

```
================================================== =========================
˘ in interface List
 11 ... 00 03 7a 81 78 c0 ...... Bluetooth Personal Area Network
 10 ... 00 1f 3c 76 27 55 ...... Intel (R) PRO / Wireless 3945ABG Network Connection
  8 ... 00 1e 68 70 8f 10 ...... 88E8040T Marvell Yukon PCI-E Fast Ethernet Controller
  1 ........................... Software Loopback Interface 1
 15 ... 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 isatap. {EAC8232A-2F30-4FB6-8F66-FAA69C4AE976}
  9 ... 02 00 54 55 4e 01 ...... Teredo Tunneling Pseudo-Interface
 16 ... 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 isatap. {274797EC-4B95-E7AC-947F-FCA2DE2D2B07}
 17 ... 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 isatap. {24D921F5-CC7F-4123-8C91-9900221A73E1}
================================================== =========================

IPv4 Route Table
================================================== =========================
Active Routes:
Network Destination Netmask Gateway Interface Metric
          0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 192.168.0.1 192.168.0.101 30
        127.0.0.0 255.0.0.0 On-link 127.0.0.1 306
        127.0.0.1 255.255.255.255 On-link 127.0.0.1 306
  127.255.255.255 255.255.255.255 On-link 127.0.0.1 306
      192.168.0.0 255.255.255.0 On-link 192.168.0.101 286
    192.168.0.101 255.255.255.255 On-link 192.168.0.101 286
    192.168.0.255 255.255.255.255 On-link 192.168.0.101 286
        224.0.0.0 240.0.0.0 On-link 127.0.0.1 306
        224.0.0.0 240.0.0.0 On-link 192.168.0.101 286
  255.255.255.255 255.255.255.255 On-link 127.0.0.1 306
  255.255.255.255 255.255.255.255 On-link 192.168.0.101 286
================================================== =========================
Routes take? Email:
  Lack

IPv6 route table
================================================== =========================
Active Routes:
 Them? If Metric Network Destination Gateway
  9 18 :: / 0 On-link
  1 306 :: 1/128 On-link
  9 18 2001 :: / 32 On-link
  9 266 2001:0:9 d38: 6ab8: 242C: 2f27: 3f57: ff9a/128
                                    On-link
 10 286 fe80 :: / 64 On-link
  9 266 fe80 :: / 64 On-link
 10 286 fe80 :: 1d96: 6b7d: 1760:908 e/128
                                    On-link
  9 266 fe80 :: 242C: 2f27: 3f57: ff9a/128
                                    On-link
  1 306 FF00 :: / 8 On-link
  9 266 FF00 :: / 8 On-link
 10 286 FF00 :: / 8 On-link
================================================== =========================
Routes take? Email:
  Lack
```

I am sorry but due to lack of much time I will continue this thread today's evening, providing some extracts from my Ubuntu. Please advise if at this point there is anything you can suggest to boost this further on.

Answer (score 0):

The status message "Destination host unreachable." most likely means that your windows box cannot even resolve a MAC address to send to (i.e. ARP-layer problem as you mentioned).

I assume you are sure that 192.168.0.12 is indeed the IP of the linux box. Did you try pinging in the other direction?